# how to get the list of indexes assign in table in cassandra

Tags: windows, indexing, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

1) Like using "DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILY schemaname.tablename" this command we can get the details of perticular table how to know the list of indexes assign to particular table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra 2 - list existing indexes with CQL 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092524/cassandra-2-list-existing-indexes-with-cql-3)

Comment: i want to know the list of name of indexes i applied to particular table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a query like below, you will get all indexes on a particular table(coulmnfamily_name in your query):

```
SELECT index_name FROM system.schema_columns 
WHERE keyspace_name='your keyspace' 
AND columnfamily_name='table name on which you want to know indexes';
```