# what leads to wide row in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I found the following from this [post](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2013/05/time-series-based-queries-in-cassandra.html):

```
create table posts(username varchar, time timeuuid, post_text varchar, primary key(username, time))
```

*There will only be as many CF rows as there are variations of the **first element** in your primary key. This can be a problem if this element has a very low cardinality as you can end up with very wide CF rows.*

My point is:

what I have bolded above, shouldn't this be second element in primary key.
That is, the secondary element or clustering element causes wide row correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem of definitions and of dictionary.
A wide-row and a row are not the same thing -- giving a definition I would say that in a Table with the PK(partition, clustering) there will be as many **wide rows** as the number of partition keys. The number of **rows** is instead given by the sum of all clustering keys for each partition.

So in the sentence you quoted the author wrote "rows" but he meant "wide-rows".

> There will only be as many CF ***wide-rows*** as there are variations of the
>   first element in your primary key. This can be a problem if this
>   element has a very low cardinality as you can end up with very **wide** CF
>   rows.

Probably at the time of writing the term wide-row was not so used.
So given such a table

```
CREATE TABLE wide_rows (
  partitionkey text,
  clusteringkey text,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((partitionkey), clusteringkey)
)
```

there will be only partitionkey wide-rows, but rows number depends on both partition and clustering

```
insert into wide_rows(partitionkey, clusteringkey, data) VALUES ( 'eagertoLearn', 'stackoverflow', 'cassandra question');
insert into wide_rows(partitionkey, clusteringkey, data) VALUES ( 'eagertoLearn', 'google groups', 'cql question');
insert into wide_rows(partitionkey, clusteringkey, data) VALUES ( 'eagertoLearn', 'askubuntu', 'linux shell question');
select * from wide_rows where partitionkey = 'eagertoLearn';

 partitionkey | clusteringkey | data
--------------+---------------+----------------------
 eagertoLearn |     askubuntu | linux shell question
 eagertoLearn | google groups |         cql question
 eagertoLearn | stackoverflow |   cassandra question

(3 rows)
```

CQL say that I've got 3 rows back, but these 3 rows belongs to the same partition key so this is 1 wide row.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what is meant by low cardinality and high cardinality as described above

Comment: By cardinality they mean the possible variations. Say you store comments, each comment has a vote from 1 to 10. If you choose vote as partition key you have a low cardinality key since you can have only 10 possible wide-row key. If you choose instead the user id you can have as many wide-rows as the user registered to the comment platform

Comment: I have posted a question on cardinality here. Please help. Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101176/high-and-low-cardinality-in-cassandra